# How to set Alpha to UIView in Storyboard with Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, storyboard

I tried to do this code.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        backGroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray.ColorWithAlpha(0.3f);}
```

However it may not work. Actually it looks like success when it displayed.

[image]

but just a second later the background color changed dark.

[image]

And suggest me regarding the same.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Mac Preview 3.

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve this issue.

I should write this in viewcontroller method.

```
public override UIModalPresentationStyle ModalPresentationStyle
    {

        get
        {
            return UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ModalPresentationStyle = value;
        }
    }
```

And Storyboard in Visual Studio for Mac Preview 3 can't chose Over Full Screen in Segue property. That's the reason why I was confused.